# Работа с числами с плавающей точкой с помощью GPU

Tags: python, геолокация, gpu, geocoding

Нужно считать расстояние между точками в пространстве, на языке python. Точки имеют динамическое расположение, поэтому результаты нет смысла кешировать. На CPU подобные расчёты производятся достаточно долго, я предполагаю из-за того, что CPU, хуже предназначен для работы с числами с плавающей точкой.

Хочу узнать, есть ли смысл использовать видеокарту, для подобных расчётов, с помощью библиотек вроде PyGPU, и каким может быть прирост в скорости?

Comment: Вопрос слишком размыт. Попробуйте уточнить проблему, добавьте детали. *Приветствие так же лишнее*

Comment: @Kromster, так нормально?

Comment: Стоит указать, сколько у вас таких точек, как они характеризуются, как вы считаете на ЦПУ, что вас не устраивает по скорости, итп итд. Также опишите проблему-первоисточник. Веротяно, что вы спрашиваете как забивать гвозди микроскопом.